# Cross-correlation of autocorrelated variables with annual time step

Tags: r, cross-correlation, autocorrelation

I am trying to analyze cross-correlations between pairs from a set of many variables with an annual time step. Currently, I have difficulties dealing with auto-correlated variables...

For each variable, I first test if it is non stationary (with both Augmented Dickey–Fuller test and Kwiatkowski–Phillips–Schmidt–Shin test), then I test if the suitably lagged and iterated difference of the first order is auto-correlated (with the estimate of the autocorrelation function).

When variables are auto-correlated, I try to prewhiten them, using an ARIMA model and then run the cross-correlation analysis.

Here is an example with 3 variables with an annual time step (31 years of data):

Auto-correlated:

```
V1 <- c(524.800, 764.449, 557.564, 615.880, 1055.453, 1290.122, 1709.981, 2113.651, 2958.380, 2541.366, 2640.039, 2787.651, 3580.520, 3907.812, 4369.220, 5003.527, 3672.161, 4394.090, 4214.062, 3671.846, 3351.458, 3036.077, 2704.647, 1854.365, 2543.996, 2106.863, 1960.762, 2036.323, 1996.526, 1940.905, 2120.696)
```

Not auto-correlated:

```
 V2 <- c(21939,20081,23702,12908,16825,23794,17748,20251,24024,19822,15272, 12258,22539,30856,24090,23512,12588,13367,11501,9099,11411,11832,11341,10899,10049,10114,10667,9902,10639,10702,10066)
```

Auto-correlated:

```
V3 <- c(3361213,  3493958,  5924759,  5283699,  9477393, 13528459, 17153250, 14509681, 27052581, 27653986, 25618494, 24642924, 31252566, 40446538, 33833710, 55843471, 31572981, 51685769, 48218752, 46947448, 52243131, 68991783, 66494239, 44108474, 67089912, 61832249, 65841550, 73992509, 62093282, 55447568, 71151920)
```

In short, what I want to see is: ccf(diff(V1),diff(V2)) and ccf(diff(V1),diff(V3))

So, here is what I did:

```
adf.test(V1)  #pvalue > 0.05 non stationary #OK
kpss.test(V1)  # pvalue < 0.05 non stationary #OK
```

the same for V2 and V3

autocorrelation function:

```
acf(diff(V1))
```

basically, if the the lag drops off sharply after time 0, V1 is not 
auto-correlated. I have also seen more precisely the output values, only for security.
the same for V2 and V3

So now comes my problem:
To get ccf(diff(V1),diff(V2)), knowing that diff(V1) is auto-correlated, I tried:

```
V1ts <- ts(V1,frequency=1) #convert to a time series
```

I suppose frequency = 1 because we only have one value per year.

```
V2ts <- ts(V2,frequency=1) #convert to a time series 

library(fpp)  #load forecasting package
mod1 <- auto.arima(V1ts)  
mod2 <- auto.arima(V1ts,D=0)
mod3 <- auto.arima(V1ts,D=1)
```

I tried also forcing D to 0 or 1.

```
library(TSA)
print(prewhiten(V1ts, V2ts, mod1))
```

with mod2 or mod3 I get the same results...

When comparing the standard ccf without dealing with autocorrelation...

```
ccf1 <- ccf(diff(V1ts),diff(V2ts))
ccf1
```

I got exactly the same results...

In conclusion, I am surely doing something wrong because I get exactly the same result with or without prewhitening...

In a nutshell, may someone help me to analyze cross-correlation of one auto-correlated variable V1 with a second one which is not auto-correlated V2 please? And in the case both variables are auto-correlated, like between V1 and V3, do I have to apply two ARIMA models and prewhiten them simultaneously?  Thank you a lot in advance, I am a bit confused here...

Comment: I omitted to precise that I followed two leads for realizing a prewhitening: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194130/cross-correlation-of-two-autocorrelated-signals-removing-autocorrelation-with-a  and also https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-015-0611-2

Comment: based on link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-015-0611-2, when both variables are autocorrelated, one of them should be prewhitened... I have tried for V1 and V3 and got same results with or without prewhitening. I really don't understand. My opinion is that the prewhitening do not change anything when the ARIMA parameters p,d,q are implemented to 0,1,0 as it was set in my case. Hope someone as a better model to propose for this kind of dataset... Thanks in advance

Comment: @user:53690 maybe do you have an answer to this kind of question: which model should I use in order to prewhiten (instead of the arima(x, order = c(0,1,0)) suggested by the auto.arima function)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user:7290 you may also have an answer? Thank in advance!